# In Linux, How to chat with other in putty, not sudo

Tags: c, linux, tty

Now, I study "write" in linux, I'm creating "new_write" which functions like "write".
So in PuTTy server, I want to send message to other user.

ex: `./new_write username1 /dev/16 ( = write username1 /dev/16)`

but I have some problem.
this server is not mine, so i don't have sudo-authority.
so, when i write like "./new_write username1 /dev/16".
An error message such as **"/dev/16: Permission denied"** is printed.

if i login in two putty through terminal(samename). 
one is user1 /dev/13 and the other is user1 /dev/14. this is not problem. because this system can chat.

In the inner function, user "write" code.

Like this :

```
while(fgets(buf, BUFSIZ, stdin) != NULL)
   if(write(fd, buf, strlen(buf)) == -1)
      break
```

i want to find this solution to solve this problem, but i don't find answer yet.
also, i didn't find anyone studying like me. Please help

Comment: A process from user A cannot write to a foreign terminal from user B. There are basically two options: Either the writing process is privileged (i.e. suid root), or user A and B both start chat programs which then communicate with each other.